# OCJP Polymorphism Flow

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding

**Hello everyone,**

I am very surprise to see the following program's output:

```
class  A{
int f() {return 0;}
int g() {return 3;}
}
class B extends A{
int f() {return 1;}
int g() {return f();}
}
class C extends B {
int f() {return 2;}
}
public class Test {
public static  void main(String args[]){
    A ref1 = new C();
    B ref2 = (B)ref1;
    System.out.println(ref2.g());
}
}
```

Please help me to explain the code.

Comment: what is the output and what don't you understand about it?

Comment: Output is: 2 but why not 1 gets printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to explain by steps:

1. Reference `ref1` points to the instance of the class `C`.
2. Reference `ref2` points to the same instance of the class `C`. No matter that it was done with explicit typecast, the instance in the heap still has the type `C`. Again:

   - `ref2` has the type `B`;
   - object instance that `ref2` is pointed to has the type `C`.
3. When we call to `ref2.g()`, JVM actually try to find method `g()` in class `C` (because object instance in heap has the type `C`, as was stated above). Because there is no method `g()` in class `C`, JVM moves to the parent class `B`, finds method `g()` in it, and calls it.
4. Call to method `g()` in class `B` leads to method `f()`. JVM again try to find that method initially in class `C`, finds it and return value `2`.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating an instance of `C` and assigning it to the `ref1` with type `A`. Further you are declaring a variable `ref2` of type `B` which get assigned the value of `ref1`. The value of `ref1` is still an instance of `C` even if you are *viewing* it by the type of class `A`.

Calling `ref2.g()` executes the method `g()` on the instance of the variable `ref2`. This is still the one and only created instance of `C`. *Looking* on it by the type of class `B` doesn't change the implementation of the instance the variable `ref2` is referring to.

Let us extend class `C` by a method `int h() { return 5; }`. Using `ref2` you cannot call method `h()` because the type of the variable is `B`. But `h()` is still present on the instance `ref2` is referring to. If you extend the main method by

```
C ref3 = (C) ref2;
System.out.println(ref3.h());
```

this will output `5`. But assigning the value of `ref2` to `ref3` and calling on it `h()` implies that the value of `ref2` and `ref3` (and `ref1`) is the same.

```
System.out.println(ref2 == ref3);
```

This outputs `true`. So both variables refer to the same object, the instance of `C`.

Comment: As we know local members always gets preference then why not it called B's f() method from return statement.

Comment: Since `ref2` is of type `B` its method `f` would be called if it wasn't overriden by `C`. But it is overriden by type `C` and the instance of the variable `ref2` is reffering to is of type `C` even if you're using it with a variable of type `B`.

Comment: @Tavash I've updated my answer with further explanations.

Answer (score 0):

This code represents overriding. And in overriding at runtime the jvm decides that which method to call (also called late binding).

Now come to code, the `class C` has the overridden method `f()` and in the code you have type-casted the reference of **class A** (`ref1`) to **class B** and called to `g()` method,  so at runtime the jvm will call `g()` method of `class B` and `ref2` is a reference of `class B`, which is pointing to `class C` object, so at runtime the `f()` method of `class C` has binded and it will call  `f()` method of `class C`.